# How to make Search panel transparent

Tags: unity, unity-tweak-tool

When I was playing around with the Unity-Tweak-Tool, my Search panel suddenly had a ugly black background (as seen in the picture below). How can I make it transparent again?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I didn’t found any perfect solution but setting up a grey color with 50% of transparency looks like default.